# Using an MIT licensed library in my project

Tags: licensing, mit

I am using a library that is under the MIT license. I never used a library that I needed to include the license before, so I have no idea where to add them. I read that I should add them in my file, but the thing is my project is a site constituting of php files, is there a certain file that I need to add the license to or all the files? Also what should I add? The project came with a LICENSE.txt file and contains text.
The project I am using is [jsModal](http://jsmodal.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but here are my recommendations.

The main requirement of the MIT license can be found on the  [jsModal license page](http://jsmodal.com/license.php)

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

If your project is a website, you should state that you are using jsModal that it is licensed under the MIT license. You need to make the entire text of the  [jsModal license page](http://jsmodal.com/license.php) (including the copyright information) available directly on your site. I do **NOT** think a simple hyperlink the the jsModal page is sufficient. The text must be a part of your web site.
If the web site is the only place you are using jsModal, you do not need to add any licensing information to any other files. A single page stating you are using jsModal with the entire text of the MIT license is sufficient.

Edit:
You should make sure that this license/copyright information is visible to the end user. Typical users won't look at your code comments, so code comments by themselves are not sufficient. You only need a single page for this license & copyright information. You don't need to add it to every page of your website.

Comment: so each page that uses this library I should include the license text? Do I add it as part of the site as in shown to the users or just a comment in each page that uses the library?

Comment: No, you don't need to have the license/copyright notice on each page. One page for your entire website is sufficient. 

You should add it as part of the site that is shown to the user. A typical user isn't going to read your code comments.

I'll update my answer to include this new information.

Comment: One more question, am I constrained to the file structure of the library or can I put the js and css files separately wherever I want?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the jsModal license either in the public directory tree where you reference the script e.g. `src/js/LICENSE.txt`. The requirement to provide a copy of the license may also be satisfied by including a link to the license in comments of the source code.

The copyright notice can be put anywhere in the source code to satisfy the copyright notice requirement. [ref](https://www.jdsupra.com/legalnews/open-source-javascript-compliance-tips-87720/)

Comment: Mat, you appear to have posted a comment to airfishey's answer as another answer. Comments/responses to answers should not be posted as new answers, but as a comment.

Comment: Removed quote to previous answer and updated answer.